# Regular Expression - Filter string have sequence of special character

Tags: c#, regex, filter

I have a string below:
`$True$Test 1$6359$$False$Test 2$372707$`

I want to take 2 group of data (example: (True, Test 1, 6359) , ...)

Could you help me for regular expression to solve this problem?

(Sorry for my bad in English)

Thanks in advance.
Anyone can help me, please?
I use C# language.

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you need. An example of code you have so far would be helpful.

Comment: Posting the expected output string would be helpful

Comment: I have edited example. Do you have some idea?

Comment: How is the pattern? 1 group every 3 $xx? Or $$ is group separator? Must be regex or could be linq?

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to use Regular expression? I think, you need simple .Split():

```
string myStr="$True$Test 1$6359$$False$Test 2$372707$";
string[] splitRes=myStr.Split(new char[]{'$'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Because I am learner, I want to know new thing :) Maybe this is the best right solution for this problem. Thanks so much!